# How to generate circle on image without using opencv functions?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
img.fill(255)
circleImg = cv2.circle(img,(256,256),63, (0,0,255), 8)
circleImg = cv2.circle(img,(256,256),63, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2_imshow(circleImg)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wSpE.jpg)

how i can get same output without using opencv functions?

Comment: Use PIL, or scikit-image maybe? What's the objection to OpenCV?

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777049/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-in-a-data-array-map-in-python)

Comment: "bresenham" for circles... -- if this is a class assignment or anything like that, you need to disclose that.